# Get value from gridview CheckBoxField on rowcommand event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a column in gridview as following

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsProcessed" HeaderText="HQ Response">
    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
</asp:CheckBoxField>
```

On gridview rowcommand event i have the following code-

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int requisitionId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("IsProcessed"); //does not work
```

But cbox is returning null. What wrong i am doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    int requisitionId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
```

Comment: What if more than one control in the cell? How to know the correct control index?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
CheckBox cbox =(CheckBox)item.FindControl("IsProcessed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of methods to expand on s.k.paul's answer.

One method gets a column value and one gets the bool value of a checkbox. The other method finds the column based on the heading.

```
public static bool gvGetCBVal(GridView gvGrid, string sHeaderText)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvGrid.SelectedRow;
    int iCol = gvGetColumn(gvGrid, sHeaderText);
    CheckBox ckBox = (CheckBox)row.Cells[iCol].Controls[0];
    return ckBox.Checked;
}

public static string gvGetVal(GridView gvGrid, string sHeaderText)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvGrid.SelectedRow;
    int iCol = gvGetColumn(gvGrid, sHeaderText);
    return row.Cells[iCol].Text;
}

private static int gvGetColumn(GridView gvGrid, string sHeaderText)
{
    int iRetVal = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < gvGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (gvGrid.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == sHeaderText.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            iRetVal = i;
        }
    }
    return iRetVal;
}
```